# How can I find the time complexity of the following snippet?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I was asked to solve a problem where I find a descending sorted triplet from an integer array A where 0<=i<j<k<n and A[i] > A[j] > A[k]. My brute-force solution was O(n^3) and after optimization, I came up with the following code and I am struggling to find its time complexity:

```py
def getTriplet2(array):
    i, j, k, n = 0, 1, 2, len(array)
    while i < j < k < n:
        if array[i] > array[j] > array[k]:
            return array[i], array[j], array[k]
        elif array[k] > array[j]:
            if i == n - 3:
                break
            if j == n - 2:
                i += 1
                j = i + 1
                k = j + 1
            if k == n - 1:
                j += 1
                k = j + 1
            else:
                k += 1
        else:
            i += 1
            j += 1
            k += 1
```

Comment: `O(3n + 5) = O(n)`

Comment: @QuangHà This is wrong. In the worst case (which is a strictly monotonous increasing array and ) all sorted triples of distinct indices are visited.

Comment: so it's `O(n^3 + 5)` = `O(n^3)`

Comment: The answers already given to this question address it completely, but if you're also looking for an efficient solution, you can do find if one exists (and find one) in linear time. The key is locating items that can exist in the middle of the triple. First you can iterate forward through the list, keeping track of the largest element encountered. At each element, either it is the largest encountered, or at least one before must have been larger so it can be a middle item. Do a very similar procedure in reverse keeping track of smallest item. Middle-of-triple candidates found twice work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially you are visiting all sorted index triples in the worst case, which would be a monotonously increasing array ( `i < j < k => A[i] < A[j] < A[k]` holds universally ).

To see this, note that for this kind of input, the branch `elif array[k] > array[j]:` of the conditional will be executed in every iteration. This branch executes in `O(1)`.

The number of index triples in ascending order is the number of index triples composed of distinct numbers, namely `O(n \over 3) = O(n^3)`.

Asymptotically your optimized solution does not run faster than brute force.